# Powerpoint videos don't auto-play the second time

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

I have created a powerpoint 2013 custom show with image links to slides with videos. I have set the videos to rewind after playing and play automatically. Whether the video finishes, and advances back to the "menu" slide or is cut off halfway, when that video slide is selected again from the menu slide, it starts at the beginning, but doesn't play automatically as it should.

Any way to make the video play automatically on the second try?

Comment: I belive this is caused by the animation pane not resetting

Comment: closing post. 'twas related to animation pane not resetting and i was using such speciallized custom shows that there's no point posting the hack solution I made, as it will not be useful to anybody else

Comment: I think you should post your solution, many solutions today are lame hacks and workarounds, if you got it to do what you were trying to get it to do, then prefer to post an answer that other people can follow.  Even if it is not "the answer" it could be enough to spur someone else into providing another one, that turns around and helps you in the long run.

Comment: alright, give me awhile. I'll post a solution eventually when i'm not super busy